# struct variable in matlab overlapping through a for loop

Tags: matlab

I am running some regression in matlab.

I want to store the varibles nicely through structures.

Here is some code:

```
    clc;                                                                                        
clear;                                                                                      
fruit_names={'Apple','Pear','Melon'};
Predictors.Apple = rand(500,11);
Predictors.Pear = rand(500,11);
Predictors.Melon = rand(500,11);
Returns.Apple = rand(500,1);
Returns.Pear = rand(500,1);
Returns.Melon = rand(500,1);
%%
 kk=1;
 for d = 1:length(fruit_names)
 for i = [1,2,3,4,5,6,12,24,48,60]
 for jj = 1:11
     K = i;
     xinit=[Predictors.(fruit_names{d})(:,jj)];
     yinit=Returns.(fruit_names{d});
     [b,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(yinit,xinit);
     Stats.(fruit_names{d})(kk+1)=stats(1);
     kk=kk+1;%to help with reporting
 end
 end   
 end
```

It honestly my best attempt at a simple example. It does require the Econometrics toolbox if I remember correctly.

The problem I am having is the structure Stats stores the results I need but after the first variables include some useless zeros.

I have posted and deleted an earlier question which suggests removing the (kk,:) variables, but if I do this it only contains the final results not the evolution of results through the for loop.

Comment: you need to reset the iterator `kk` for each `fruit_names`, otherwise after the first fruit is proccessed, `kk` already reached value `11xnumel(i)=110`. When the next fruit is processed, `kk` starts at 111 ...

Comment: How can I do what you propose

Comment: I think @user22485 answer below did just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the position of the kk variable that is the problem.

It seems like you need to collect the results from the second two loops.

```
clc;                                                                                        
clear;                                                                                      
fruit_names={'Apple','Pear','Melon'};
Predictors.Apple = rand(500,11);
Predictors.Pear = rand(500,11);
Predictors.Melon = rand(500,11);
Returns.Apple = rand(500,1);
Returns.Pear = rand(500,1);
Returns.Melon = rand(500,1);
%%

 for d = 1:length(fruit_names)

 kk=1; %move the kk = 1 variable here.

 for i = [1,2,3,4,5,6,12,24,48,60]
 for jj = 1:11
     K = i;
     xinit=[Predictors.(fruit_names{d})(:,jj)];
     yinit=Returns.(fruit_names{d});
     [b,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(yinit,xinit);
     Stats.(fruit_names{d})(kk+1)=stats(1);
     kk=kk+1;%to help with reporting
 end
 end   
 end
```

Enjoy your fruit!